# Unable to cast object of type 'Common.Date' to type 'System.IConvertible C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, operator-overloading

I have seen this error message problem in stackoverflow, but neither of them was for datetime or date type in order to work with only date type I have made a class of date type and has written some overloads for it in the date class. My date class is

```
using System;
namespace Common 
{
    public class Date
    {
        private DateTime _d1;

        public Date(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            _d1 = dateTime;
        }

        public static bool operator <(Date date1, Date date2)
        {
            bool flag = false;


            //Now, get the original DateTime Type of C#
            DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
            DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);

            //Now compare the two DateTime variables and assign the flag to true 
            //if the first date is smaller than the second date
            int result = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }

        public static bool operator >(Date date1, Date date2)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            //Now, get the original DateTime Type of C#
            DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
            DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);

            //Now compare the two DateTime variables and assign the flag to true 
            //if the first date is Greater than the second date
            int result = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(Date date1, Date date2)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            //Now, get the original DateTime Type of C#
            DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
            DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);

            //Now compare the two DateTime variables and assign the flag to true 
            //if the first date is Greater than the second date
            int result = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            if (result <= 0)
            {
                flag = true;
            }

            return flag;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(Date date1, Date date2)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            //Now, get the original DateTime Type of C#
            DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
            DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);

            //Now compare the two DateTime variables and assign the flag to true 
            //if the first date is Greater than the second date
            int result = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            if (result >= 0)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Date date1, Date date2)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            //Now, get the original DateTime Type of C#
            DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
            DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);

            //Now compare the two DateTime variables and assign the flag to true 
            //if the first date is Greater than the second date
            int result = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Date date1, Date date2)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            //Now, get the original DateTime Type of C#
            DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
            DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);

            //Now compare the two DateTime variables and assign the flag to true 
            //if the first date is Greater than the second date
            int result = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }
    }//end of class Date
}//End of namespace
```

but The problem is while I am trying to use in my code behind page its giving me this error -- Unable to cast object of type 'Common.Date' to type 'System.IConvertible

the code where I am using it like 
    Date purchaseDate = new Date(item.PurchaseDate);
                        Date submissionSate = new Date(item.SubmissionDate);

```
                    if (purchaseDate>submissionSate)
                    {
                        //to do
                    }
```

here in the item object the purchasedate and submision date are datetime properties and the error is in the if line
Can anyone provide me any suggesion? what is the probable solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `>` operator overload, you have

```
DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1); 
DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);
```

and there is no overload of `Convert.ToDateTime` that takes your `Date` object, so you are calling [`Convert.ToDateTime(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky38w316.aspx), which requires `object` to implement [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx).

You can implement `IConvertible`, or just compare the `_d1` values as @ChaosPandion mentions.

Comment: Could not understand properly, would you please explain it a bit further? it would be so nice of you.

Comment: If you take a look at the overloads for [`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw6yd06a.aspx), you'll see that the only one that can be called is `Convert.ToDateTime(object)`, and in order for `Convert.ToDateTime` to work, `object` must implement the `IConvertible` interface (see the documentation).  Since your `Date` class does not implement `IConvertible`, `Convert.ToDateTime(date1)` throws the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access the fields of `Date`. Although I question the usefulness of this `Date` object.

```
public static bool operator <(Date date1, Date date2)
{
    return date1 != null && date2 != null && date1._d1 < date2._d1
}
```

Comment: Actually I wrote the date class to learn the operator overloading in c#, and then how to use them, and r you sure the --date1._d1 < date2._d1 portion of code gonna work?

Comment: @Pankouri - All private members are accessible within the scope of `Date`.